# What pattern should I use to express a Hierarchical Enum?

Tags: c#, architecture, enums, design-patterns

I'm experimenting with an API for publishing values at a given time (tuples of value and time). These samples will be used by a data viewer (e.g. a graph).

I want to associate the value with a Quantity and a Unit, for example length in meters. That way my "viewer" can scale it appropriately.

I'm looking for a sort of hierarchical enum, like this:

```
enum Quantity
{
   Mass.Kg,
   Mass.g,
   Length.m,
   Length.mm
}
```

But this doesn't exist in C#.

I'm not sure the best pattern to express this and I've come up with the following. Is there a recognised, or better way to do this?

```
using System;
using Moq;

namespace ConsoleApplication26
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //use a Mock to play with the API
            Mock<ITelemetryPublisherFactory> mockTelemetryPublisherFactory = new Mock<ITelemetryPublisherFactory>();
            var telemetryPublisherFactory = mockTelemetryPublisherFactory.Object;

            //example usages
            var massTelemetryPublisher = telemetryPublisherFactory.GetChannelSamplePublisher<Double>("My Mass", Mass.Kg);
            massTelemetryPublisher.PublishChannelSampleAtTimeNow(83.4);                        

            var lengthTelemetryPublisher = telemetryPublisherFactory.GetChannelSamplePublisher<Int32>("My Height", Length.μm);
            lengthTelemetryPublisher.PublishChannelSampleAtTimeNow(1800000);      

            //10 years time..
            lengthTelemetryPublisher.PublishChannelSampleAtTimeNow(1800000);
            massTelemetryPublisher.PublishChannelSampleAtTimeNow(120.1);                        
        }
    }

    public interface ITelemetryPublisherFactory
    {
        ITelemetryPublisher<T> GetChannelSamplePublisher<T>(String channelName, Quantity quantity);
    }

    public interface ITelemetryPublisher<T>
    {
        void PublishChannelSampleAtTimeNow(T sampleValue);
    }

    public abstract class Quantity {}

    public class Mass : Quantity
    {
        private enum Unit
        {
            g,
            Kg
        }

        private readonly Unit _unit;

        private Mass(Unit unit)
        {
            _unit = unit;
        }

        public static Quantity Kg {get { return new Mass(Unit.Kg); }}
        public static Quantity g { get { return new Mass(Unit.g); } }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Mass.{0}", _unit);
        }
    }

    public class Length : Quantity
    {
        private enum Unit
        {
            m,
            mm,
            μm,
            beardSecond
        }

        private readonly Unit _unit;

        private Length(Unit unit)
        {
            _unit = unit;
        }

        public static Quantity m { get { return new Length(Unit.m); } }
        public static Quantity mm { get { return new Length(Unit.mm); } }
        public static Quantity μm { get { return new Length(Unit.μm); } }
        public static Quantity beardSecond { get { return new Length(Unit.beardSecond); } }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Length.{0}", _unit);
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but consider F# and [Units of Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to create a `Unit` class for the unit of measure and a `Quantity` class that associates a unit of measure with an amount. Look at the [Quantity pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) for the idea. Since you also want to record the "type" of the unit of measure, you could create a `UnitType` class that records that information:

```
public sealed partial class UnitType {
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public UnitType(string name) {
    Name = name;
  }
}

public sealed partial class Unit {
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public UnitType Type { get; private set; }
  public Unit(string name, UnitType type) {
    Name = name;
    Type = type;
  }
}
```

(You should make them proper value types by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`)

The `Unit` class can be extended to provide for e.g. conversions, compound units, formatting and parsing.

Then, you can define the common cases inside the classes:

```
public partial class UnitType {
  public static readonly UnitType Mass = new UnitType("Mass");
  public static readonly UnitType Length = new UnitType("Length");
}

public partial class Unit {
  public static readonly Unit Grams = new Unit("g", UnitType.Mass);
  public static readonly Unit Kilos = new Unit("kg", UnitType.Mass);
  // ...
}
```

Or define your "hierarchies" with static classes:

```
public static class Mass {
  public static readonly UnitType Type = new UnitType("Mass");

  public static readonly Unit Grams = new Unit("g", Type);
  public static readonly Unit Kilos = new Unit("kg", Type);
  ...
}

public static class Length ...
```

The `Quantity` class would also be an immutable value type (just showing its usage):

```
var eniacWeight = new Quantity(27, Mass.Tons);
```

Or you could use extension methods to create `Quantity`s:

```
var eniacWeight = 27.Tons();
```

(from [ENIAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC))

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Fowler pattern, very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested approach seems reasonable to me, and I use something similar in a project of mine. However, I keep the actual value part of the object, and I use `struct` instead of `class`, since they are naturally value types. Inheritance is not necessary here (and not possible with structs, anyways), so I use an interface to create a contract and act as a constraint when needed (I called it `IUnitOfMeasure`).

I do not recommend creating one enum with all the units of the various types of measurement combined; it is hell validating the unit to make sure someone didn't reference a Mass unit when working with Length.

```
public interface IUnitOfMeasure<TThis>
    where TThis : IUnitOfMeasure<TThis>
{
    TThis ConvertTo(TThis value);
}

public struct Mass : IUnitOfMeasure<Mass>
{
    public enum Units
    {
        Gram,
        Kilogram
    }

    private double _value;
    private Mass.Units _unit;

    public double Value { get { return _value; } }

    public Mass.Units Unit { get { return _unit; } }

    public Mass(double value, Mass.Units unit)
    {
        _value = value;
        _unit = unit;
    }

    public Mass ConvertTo(Mass value)
    {
        switch(value.Unit)
        {
            case Units.Gram:
                return new Mass(Unit == Units.Gram ? Value : Value/1000, Units.Gram);
            case Units.Kilogram:
                return new Mass(Unit == Units.Gram ? Value*1000 : Value, Units.Kilogram);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Value, Unit);
    }

    public static readonly Mass G = new Mass(0, Units.Gram);
    public static readonly Mass Kg = new Mass(0, Units.Kilogram);
}
```

Usage:

```
var kg = new Mass(5.0, Mass.Units.Kilogram);

Console.WriteLine(kg); // writes "5 Kilogram"

var g = kg.ConvertTo(Mass.G);

Console.WriteLine(g); // writes ".005 Gram"
```

If you don't care about keeping the value, and just want to keep enum/static values in a central place:

```
public static class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public enum Mass
    {
      Gram,
      Kilogram
    }

    public enum Length
    {
       Meter,
       Kilometer
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Usage: `var unit = UnitOfMeasure.Mass.Kilogram;`

Comment: I can't use the last idea in your post, thanks for the interface idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Enums are primitive types and cannot inherit from other enums, as inheritance is a property of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical enum isn't possible, as noted above. If you're exclusively using metric, though, you can utilise standard prefixes if it helps.

```
enum MeasurementUnits
{
    Gram,
    Metre,
    Litre,
    Hectare
    // etc
}

enum MeasurementPrefix
{
    Milli,
    Natural,
    Kilo,
    Mega
    // etc
}
```

This may not be precisely what you want, but it will provide the type of 'grouping' that you might be looking for (e.g. group measurements that are about length, weight etc by checking their 'units' value).

Comment: That's a great idea, I like it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot introduce inheritance with enums. Enums are just a convenience mechanism to allow you to use meaningful textual identifiers in your code. From The code you have, I suggest you either use an enum like;

```
public enum UnitOfMeasure
{
    MassGrams,
    MassKg,
    LengthMM,
    LengthCM,
    . . .
}
```

Or split it out to where it's appropriate, so that Mass and Length are defined separately for example.

The 'inheritance' is just something you've introduced in your thinking about this problem, but it isn't necessary to your solution. When you want to deal with Mass, you only look at the flags/enums appropriate to mass.